# How do i tell Xcode NOT to trim transparent edges when packing texture atlases

Tags: xcode, textures, trim, sktexture, sktextureatlas

How do i tell Xcode NOT to trim transparent edges when packing texture atlases.
[image]

Comment: More info please. Like why do you want to do this?

Comment: i have a frame by frame character animation and i need keep the character's position in the frame at it was drawn in the animation

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. Xcode will trim these transparent areas to pack the textures closer together, but they are supposed to be added back in when loaded into your game. The atlases would be useless if it didn't do this. Still not enough information, are you using Xcode's built in atlas support, or using something else?

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure about it. Thanks.